# How to get the minimum value of a mysql-table column based on the number sequence in a row

Tags: mysql, minimum

I have a mysql-table (results) with six columns like this:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | can_1 | can_2 | can_3 | can_4 | can_5 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |     0 |     2 |     4 |     3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  2 |     2 |     1 |     5 |     3 |     4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  3 |     3 |     1 |     0 |     0 |     0 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  4 |     0 |     2 |     1 |     0 |     3 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I am trying to grab rows with the least value **larger than 1** from the can_1 column based on what ever values are stored in each row.

For example: can_1 needs to return rows (id) 2 and 3, since 2 is the min value on row 2 and 3 is the min value of row 3.

Using

```
SELECT id FROM results WHERE can_1 = (SELECT MIN(can_1) FROM results);
```

returns

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```

This is understandable - the MIN-value checks for the minimum value larger than 1 in the entire column (can_1), which is 2 in the can_1 case. But how do I combine this so the minimum value of the **entire** row (covering all columns) determines what minimum values to return for the can_1 column, ie. for the result to be this?

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
|  3 |
+----+
```

Comment: In what way is 2 the min value of row 2 and 3 the min value of row 3? Compared to the other columns it isn't, and neither to the other row values of can_1.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm looking for the minimum value larger than 1 (I even made it bold). 2 is then the minimum value for row 2 and 3 for row 3...

Comment: What do you mean by 'values for row 2'? Each row has only 1 value for each  column (can_1 in this case). What other values does row 2 have? Because can_2 for row 2 is smaller than can_1.

Comment: Okay - i see what you mean. I need to clarify my question. Hang on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the function `LEAST()`:

```
select id
from tablename
where can_1 > 1
and can_1 = least(
  can_1, 
  case when can_2 <= 1 then can_1 + 1 else can_2 end, 
  case when can_3 <= 1 then can_1 + 1 else can_3 end, 
  case when can_4 <= 1 then can_1 + 1 else can_4 end, 
  case when can_5 <= 1 then can_1 + 1 else can_5 end
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMuBs7o2kcQJCXPx4AGvtb/0).
Results:

```
| id  |
| --- |
| 2   |
| 3   |
```

Comment: Just another way (maybe not that performant):https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMuBs7o2kcQJCXPx4AGvtb/1 I think it works in all cases too.

Comment: Any examples to impacts my learning of the basics of MySQL is favourable to me. I'm tremendously grateful for you showing this to me. I've been hitting my head over this for weeks trying to fix it without asking for help about it.

Comment: I just have one follow-up question. This query supposes that 3 must be the closest "least" value after 2. But it might just as well be 4 or 5 depending on the number of zeroes in the row, ie. 1,0,0,0,5. Then 5 would be the minimum integer. can_x + 1 treats the following integer after 2 (3), but since the sequence is created dynamically I never know on forehand what the closest minimum value would be. How would I solve that using the same technique given in your answer? :)

Comment: Why do you use the word "closest"? There is no approximation here. The expression `can_1 + 1` is used to make sure that if a number is <=1 then it is treated as greater than `can_1` and the reason is that it must be excluded from least().

Comment: I guess I failed in my explanation. :) Isn’t can_1 + 1 always equal to 3 if the number is <= 1? I must admit that I might be falling behind in understanding the function of LEAST.

Comment: No, can_1 + 1 is what the expression returns. If in a row can_1 is 3 then can_1 + 1 is 4.